# Place Osmand maps to SD card

Tags: sd-card, osmand

I have Osmand running on Huawei Y560 with 5.1.1. Osmand was running in internal storage. I have performed "move to SD card" operation. Currently maps folder is set to `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/net.osmand.plus/files`. Looks this folder is in internal memory anyway. I'm trying to change folder to `/storage/sdcard1/osmand` , but Osmand complains that it can't write to this directory. How to place maps to external card?

Answer (score 2):

Simply go to

1. OsmAnd settings, General settings (to configure common settings for the application)
2. Under Miscellaneous, Tap Data storage folder, there is a pop-up info to ask where you want to store your Maps data.
3. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting "Storage 2" or other pre-definded storage-names concerning the SD-card does NOT help, if Android or whoever insists of the real name of the SD-Card (which may be e.g. "22E-23D..." and not simply "extSDcard" or "storage 2").

You can get this name of your SD, if you look in the properties e.g. of a jpg-file which is stored on your SD-Card. If you look closely on the different items of "properties", you will discover "details" (or some item named similiar to that). There you will find the path to your jpg-file and in the path-name you will see - at last - the real name of your SD-card.
That's it.

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]

Comment: unfortunately did not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Both of the above answers did not work for me. But today - just by chance - I came across this discussion here on github:
https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand/issues/1838
Some people in there are mentioning problems they had when the app itself was pushed to SD. I had a look, and indeed my tablet's "move apps to SD" feature had moved OSMAND to the card. After I had moved it back I could select "Multi user storage 2" (in German: "Mehrbenutzer-Speicher 2") in Osmand's settings. This was the only option really working, and since it did I didn't bother going through more experiments. All files are now stored below

```
/storage/[sdcard-ID]/Android/obb/net.osmand.plus
```

Hopefully that stays as it is now

Answer (score 0):

After having moved the app to the SD card via the app preferences (as you did it already) I was able to select "Interner App-speicher" (which should translate to internal app storage) which also showed a path to

```
/mnt/expand/.../user/0/net.osmand.plus/no_backup
```

which is where my external sdcard is mounted. So I assume that the internal app storage is on the external sd card as soon as the app is moved there. Also the free storage was then displayed correctly. osmand 3.0.4, android 6.0.1.